# Como tornar um refresh mais dinâmico?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Há algum método de buscar dados de um servidor pondo diretamente para uma página sem ter que utilizar um exemplo básico de javascript: ??

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "retorno.php",
       data: 'id=1',
       cache: false,
       success: function(html) {
           $("div").html(html);
       }
   });
}, 1000);
```

Porque com esse tipo de exemplo não posso fazer com que seja mais dinâmico com a página. 
**EXEMPLO:**

Se for para listar uma conversa entre duas pessoas, com esse código, não posso soltar um som de notificação para alertar o usuário de mensagem nova.

Há algum jeito de mesmo que use esse tipo de código faça com que de pra manuseá-lo, porque em `setInterval` a página ficaria dando *refresh* de tempo em tempo impedindo de analisar o código.

Tipo a notificação do Facebook onde aparenta ser diretamente na página e só notifica quando ha mudança no servidor.

Comment: Você pode dá uma estudada em websocket, talvez resolva seu problema.

É melhor que ficar se conectando com o servidor a cada X segundos.

Imagina se uma um garçom fica perguntando a cada minuto se o prato está pronto. Terrivel!

O Chefe é quem notifica o garçom, Esse é o modelo ideal.

Da mesma forma o teu browser ficar requisitando ao servidor a cada X segundos é muito ruim. 
Deixa que o servidor notifique de alguma mudança ao cliente especifico.

Use técnica [comet][1]
    [1]: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar WebSocket, embora indiretamente o procedimento de servidores seja o mesmo, só que executado por uma thread na camada de aplicação do software. No caso do WebSocket existe um serviço/Thread que executa validação dos dados e envia um retorno para o browser, o qual fica aguardando a resposta (Listining). Um link interesante para analisar algumas das alternativas de WebSocket (HTML5). 
http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Nesta URL encontramos algumas linguagens nas quais podemos instanciar nosso servidor de WebSocket, Java, .Net, NodeJS, entre outras.

Outra referência interesante sobre WebSocket
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

No site da IBM tem um exemplo legal de bate-papo com WebSocket
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/wa-bluemix-html5chat/index.html